# How to validate config options for a Gatsby Plugin?

Tags: plugins, gatsby

As a Gatsby Plugin author, I want to apply some validations, e.g. the `gatsby-config` needs to include a `requestor` key-value pair for my plugin.  The documentation is sparse.

I have tried simply throwing an error inside of my `exports.createResolvers` call, it didn't seem to work.

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }, configOptions) => {
  throw new Error(`Query Parameter 'requestor' is required`)
}
```

I expected this to break my build but `gatsby build` continued happily on past the plugin-loading step.

Comment: why don't you ask users of your plugin to pass in whatever data you need via `configOptions` & validate it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an error from within the `gatsby-node` did, after all, work. I had typos in my parent project which were preventing me from seeing the errors.

It *does* work to do what I did in the question.